# grails spring secruity plugin redirect after login

Tags: grails

In grails I am trying to direct user after login to my person controller. I tried to add redirection in config.groovy but it is not working. It still redirects me back to login page.

My `config.grooovy` Spring security section is below

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'grail4.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'grail4.UserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'grail4.Role'

//grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = 'https://www.yahoo.com'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/index'

grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [



 '/people/*':   ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'],   

   ]

***grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl ="/people"***
```

After putting right username password I can access the person class page if I copy & paste the URL. But the login page is not redirecting it to that page.

Answer (score 0):

Following should work -

```
 grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/people'
```

Looks  like user is NOT  successfully authenticated. You  should try registering spring security listener

1. in Config.groovy

   ```
   grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
   ```
2. implement a security listener-

   ```
   class MySecurityEventListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {
   static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(CGWSecurityEventListener.class);

   public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationEvent e) {
       if (e instanceof AbstractAuthenticationEvent) {
           if (e instanceof AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) {
               logger.warn(String.format("Authentication failure",    ((AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) e).getAuthentication().principal),
                       ((AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent) e).getException());
           }
           else if (e instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent) {
               logger.debug(String.format("user %s has been authenticated sucessfully", ((AuthenticationSuccessEvent) e).getAuthentication().principal))
           }
       }

   }
   ```

   }

http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/7%20Events.html#7.2%20Registering%20an%20Event%20Listener